# Better way to define custom list type in Unicode Number in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would want to make a custom list type of Khmer Unicode Number `១ ២ ៣..` orderly. I tried to archive this by using css css pseudo `li:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3)..` as define in my stylesheet like this:

```
ul.mainList {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.mainList > li {
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "១. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "២. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "៣. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(4):before {
  content: "៤. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(5):before {
  content: "៥. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(6):before {
  content: "៦. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(7):before {
  content: "៧. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.mainList > li:nth-child(8):before {
  content: "៨. ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
```

My HTML markup is like so:

```
<p>List of items</p>
<ul class="mainList">
    <li>Item ១</li>
    <li>Item ២</li>
    <li>Item ៣</li>
    <li>Item ៤</li>
    <li>Item ៥</li>
    <li>Item ៦</li>
    <li>Item ៧</li>
    <li>Item ៨</li>
</ul>
```

It works just fine, however supposed if I had than ten or twenty list items, I would have to define ten or twenty `li:nth-child(n)` twenty times as well.

Any thought of a better way? Thanks

Comment: `ul.mainList > li:before {
  text-indent: -5px;
}`

Comment: `ul.mainList > li:before { text-indent: -5px; }`, I want to make my paragraph in list item indented `-5px` from it current is. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a not very known feature but the `list-style` CSS attribute can accept a very wide range of values (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)). Including `khmer`! So you are in luck, the easiest way is to simply define the `list-style` of your **ordered list**...

```css
ol.khmer {
  list-style: khmer;
}
```

```html
<p>List of items</p>
<ol class="khmer">
  <li>Item ១</li>
  <li>Item ២</li>
  <li>Item ៣</li>
  <li>Item ៤</li>
  <li>Item ៥</li>
  <li>Item ៦</li>
  <li>Item ៧</li>
  <li>Item ៨</li>
</ol>
```

I find important to note that it is not all browsers that support it, as stated by @Mr_Lister. The other option could be using [@counter-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) which is not supported much more... If all browsers should be supported, you'd have to stick to your solution.